# how tornado cash commitment is safe?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, privacy, tornado-cash

When you deposit funds to tornado cash, you get a secret which is called "commitment". When you withdraw funds, you pass this secret, zk-Stark algorithm can detect which deposit belongs to this secret and you get your deposit.

My question is how this secret is safe? when you send the transaction, can't miner see the secret and execute a transaction using this safe key?

Answer (score 1):

as we know starkware uses ZK, and actually, you do not need to show your secret to the validator to accept your transaction in ZK, it uses an interactive proof system to proof each transaction, the easiest way to understand ZK proof is [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxbgsamAtW8) and for further understanding, you can read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof).